# Is Peter's use of Tartarus adoptive of Hellenistic language or ideas?

Tags: greek, 2-peter, afterlife

We see here in 2 Peter 2:4 reference to what in most English translations is "hell", but in the Greek is "Tartarus" (as usually noted in the footnotes):

> For if God did not spare angels when they sinned, but **sent them to hell**, putting them into gloomy dungeons to be held for judgment...
>
> Εἰ γὰρ ὁ θεὸς ἀγγέλων ἁμαρτησάντων οὐκ ἐφείσατο ἀλλὰ σειραῖς ζόφου **ταρταρώσας** παρέδωκεν εἰς κρίσιν τηρουμένους...

[Tartarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartarus), I understand, is part of the Greek mythological cosmology where souls are tormented in a dark pit or abyss far below even Hades.

Is the use of the term here by Peter indicative of an adoption/acceptance of Hellenistic ideas of the underworld? (I.e. did Peter follow somewhat a Greek conception of the afterlife?) Or is it merely an appropriation of Hellenistic language to make a point to a particular audience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ταρταρώσας is defined as:

> **ταρταρόω** (Τάρταρος ‘the Netherworld’) 1 aor. ἐταρτάρωσα (Acusilaus
>   Hist. [V B.C.]: 2 Fgm. 8 Jac. I p. 50; Lydus, Men. 4, 158 p. 174, 26
>   W.; cp. Sext. Emp., Pyrrh. Hypot. 3, 24, 210 ὁ Ζεὺς τὸν Κρόνον
>   κατεταρτάρωσεν [this compound several times in Ps.—Apollod.: 1, 1, 4;
>   1, 2, 1, 2; 1, 2, 3]. Tartarus, thought of by the Greeks as a
>   subterranean place lower than Hades where divine punishment was meted
>   out, and so regarded in Israelite apocalyptic as well: Job 41:24; En
>   20:2; Philo, Exs. 152; Jos., C. Ap. 2, 240; SibOr 2, 302; 4, 186) **hold
>   captive in Tartarus** 2 Pt 2:4.—DELG s.v. Τάρταρος. M-M.<sup>1</sup>

It is used in Hesiod’s *Theogony* as the prison of the ancient Greek deities (the Titans); this is a classical Greek story with conceptual parallels to Gen 6:1–4. Tartarus is thus a place of extreme torment, in contrast to Elysium, the place of the blessed.<sup>2</sup> In 2 Peter the name is used of the infernal region to which the rebellious angels were consigned, and hence here signifies a place of punishment of the wicked.<sup>3</sup> According to another commentary,

> One of the most prominent themes of ancient Jewish tradition, though
>   usually suppressed by the later rabbis, was the idea that the “sons of
>   God” in Genesis 6:1–3 were angels who lusted after women and so fell.
>   The term for “cast into hell” here is from the Greek name Tartarus, a
>   place not only of holding for the wicked dead (and especially the
>   Titans, the pre-Olympian supernatural beings), but of the severest
>   conceivable tortures; it occurs elsewhere in Jewish literature as the
>   place where the fallen angels were imprisoned. Jewish writers also
>   generally affirmed a current hell as a holding place for the wicked
>   until the final judgment.<sup>4</sup>

Peter may have intentionally wrote in such a way as to allude both to pagan mythology as well as the biblical narrative.

> 2 Peter is a piece of apology and polemic, responding to a crisis in
>   the church over God’s theodicy and the eschatological doctrine of the
>   Parousia as the end of the world and its judgment. First, 2 Peter
>   claims that heretics are already in the church: ‘false prophets’ who
>   speak peace when doom is coming (2:1-3) and ‘scoffers’ who mock ‘the
>   promise of his coming’ (3:3-4). They argue from the delay of the day
>   of judgment that God will not judge; from the eternity of the world
>   they argue against its predicted end.
>
> Second, in response to this heresy, 2 Peter defends God’s coming
>   judgment, appealing to images intelligible to pagans and Christians
>   alike. The author affirms that ‘God did not spare’ the evil angels
>   (2:4), Noah’s world (2:5), or Sodom and Gomorrah (2:6-8). As God once
>   destroyed the world by water, so he can end it by fire (3:5-7). The
>   biblical allusions are clear, but these examples could also be
>   understood by pagans as references to their traditional myths of the
>   Titans cast into Tartarus, the flood of Deucalion and Phyrra, and the
>   fiery destruction of Phaethon. From these examples, 2 Peter concludes
>   with the principle that God both rewards and punishes: ‘God knows how
>   to rescue the godly…and to keep the unrighteous under punishment until
>   the day of judgment’ (2:9-10). Third, he defends God’s alleged
>   ‘slowness’ in judging. God’s time is mysterious, as the psalmist noted
>   (3:8). God’s ‘slowness’ is really God’s long-suffering, giving sinners
>   time to repent (3:9). Even Paul, notoriously difficult to understand,
>   agrees with 2 Peter on God’s slowness to judge as God’s gift of
>   long-suffering (3:15-16; see Rom. 2:4-6).<sup>5</sup>

Based not only on the use here of ταρταρόω<sup>6</sup>, but also on the near universal acceptance of New Testament writers of using ᾅδης (Hades) as a translation for שְׁאוֹל (Sheol, although ᾅδης is not used by Peter), it seems very plausible that the early Christians used Hellenistic terms and concepts concerning the after-life but assigned to them slightly altered meanings from Jewish thought.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>William Arndt, Frederick W. Danker and Walter Bauer, A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature, 3rd ed. (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2000), 991.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>John D. Barry, Michael R. Grigoni, Michael S. Heiser et al., Faithlife Study Bible (Bellingham, WA: Logos Bible Software, 2012), 2 Pe 2:4.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>Allen C. Myers, The Eerdmans Bible Dictionary (Grand Rapids, MI: Eerdmans, 1987), 479.</sub>

<sup>4</sup> <sub>Craig S. Keener, The IVP Bible Background Commentary: New Testament (Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity Press, 1993), 2 Pe 2:4.</sub>

<sup>5</sup> <sub>Paul J. Achtemeier, Harper & Row and Society of Biblical Literature, Harper’s Bible Dictionary, 1st ed. (San Francisco: Harper & Row, 1985), 780.</sub>

<sup>6</sup> <sub>It should also be noted that Jude alludes to this as well (the books are very similar and one likely had the other as its source).</sub>