# What are the "gates of Sheol"? Isaiah 38:10

Tags: word-study, isaiah, death, terminology

Isaiah 38:10 (ESV):

> I said, In the middle of my days I must depart; I am consigned to **the gates of Sheol** for the rest of my years.

We find similar expressions by David, Job and Jesus:

> Be gracious to me, O Lord! See my affliction from those who hate me, O you who lift me up from **the gates of death**,
> [Psalm 9:13 ESV]

> they loathed any kind of food, and they drew near to **the gates of death**.
> [Psalm 107:18 ESV]

> Have the gates of death been revealed to you, or have you seen **the gates of deep darkness**? [Job 38:17 ESV]

> 18 And I also say to you that you are Peter, and upon this rock I will build My church; and the **gates of Hades** will not overpower it.
> [Matthew 16:18 NASB]

What are the "gates of Sheol"?

---

Related: [What is hell? sheol/hades/prison/lake of fire/outer darkness](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/59614/38524)

Comment: A similar question has been asked on Christianity in relation to Matthew 16:18 -- https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1096

Answer (score 1):

"The gates of death" is a Hebraism that almost personifies the grave and death.  Observe the Cambridge commentary on Job 38:17 -

> 17. **have the gates of death** Or, were the gates? Death is personified; it is Sheol, the place of the dead, ch. Job 28:22. This
>     is a lower deep than the recesses of the sea; Job, no doubt, went down
>     there also.

We see this in the surrounding material (V6-8):

> On what were its [the earth] **foundations** set, or who laid its
> **cornerstone**, ... Who enclosed the sea behind **doors** when it burst forth from the **womb**

Thus, there is considerable literary metaphor and licence in the passage of Job 38.

There is a similar phenomenon in other places that talk about death and sheol/hades.  For example, in Isa 38, Isaiah expresses a lament in very poetic language using numerous metaphors such as (V12, 13):

> My dwelling has been picked up and removed from me **like a shepherd’s
> tent**. I have **rolled up my life like a weaver**; He cuts me off
> **from the loom**; from day until night You make an end of me. I composed myself until the morning. Like a **lion** He breaks **all my
> bones**; from day until night You make an end of me.

In the case of Ps 9 we have the helpful comments of Ellicott:

> (13, 14) It is natural to take these verses as the cry for help just
> mentioned. Consider.—Literally, see my suffering from my haters.
>
> My lifter up from the gates of death.—For the gates of sheol, see Note
> to Psalm 6:5. (Comp. Psalm 107:18, and the Homeric phrase “the gates
> of Hades.”) We might perhaps paraphrase “from the verge of the grave,”
> if it were not for the evident antithesis to “gates of the daughter of
> Zion” in the next verse. We understand, therefore, “gates” in sense of
> “power,” “rule,” the gate being the seat of the judge or king, and so,
> like our “court,” synonymous for his power. (Comp. Sublime Porte.)

This shows the pattern of the Hebrew metaphor well.  There are no literal gates of sheol/hades.

Answer (score 0):

שְׁאוֹל The "Grave" [is] Prison (where souls can remain cut off from living) based on Jonah 2:3 & Isaiah 38:10 which is deep under the earth; the opposite of heaven (where souls live eternally) [compared with Psalms. 139:8] - it does not mean hell.

[Psalms 139:8] - "If I ascend to heaven, You are" there; (אִם־אֶסַּק שָׁמַיִם שָׁם אָתָּה ) "if I descend to Sheol, You are there too" (וְאַצִּיעָה שְּׁאוֹל הִנֶּֽךָּ).

Prison (like a grave) is below earth. | The "gates" of Sheol are prison doors like the jaws of a great fish in [Jonah 2:3] "And he said: I called out from my distress to the Lord, and He answered me; from the belly of the **Sheol** I cried out, You heard my voice." (וַיֹּאמֶר קָ֠רָא֠תִי מִצָּ֥רָה לִ֛י אֶל־יְהֹוָה וַיַּֽעֲנֵנִי מִבֶּ֧טֶן שְׁא֛וֹל שִׁוַּעְתִּי שָׁמַעְתָּ קוֹלִֽי)

**Lifelong Imprisonment is described in [Isaiah 38:10]**- I said, "In the desolation of my days will I go into the gates of the grave; I am deprived of the rest of my years." (אֲנִי אָמַ֗רְתִּי בִּדְמִי יָמַי אֵלֵכָה בְּשַֽׁעֲרֵי שְׁא֑וֹל פֻּקַּ֖דְתִּי יֶתֶר שְׁנוֹתָֽי) - Gates of Sheol are simply doors to prison, where a person is cut off from living life.

Answer (score 0):

Are the words "Sheol" and "jail" related etymologically? I am convinced they are, but I cannot find proof of this.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/45995)

Comment: As this site looks for specific answers to specific questions, then it would be best to hold back from a mere comment until you have found the necessary proof for your view.